# Breaking up a string into separate elements

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to write an algorithm that will take in a string and find the individual words within it, then push that word into a vector.

```
void setChar(string s)
{
    {
    int i = 0;


    while(i != s.size())
    {

        while( i != s.size() && isspace(s[i]))
            i++;

        int j = i;

        while(j != s.size() && !isspace(s[j]))
            j++;

        if(i != j)
        {

            words.push_back(s.substr(i, j));
            cout<<"Successfully stored the word "<<s.substr(i, j)<<endl;
            i = j;
        }

    }
    return;
    }
}
```

The algorithm runs, but gives me weird results. When I put in the string "The turtle is very happy", I get:

> Successfully stored the word the
>
> Successfully stored the word turtle is
>
> Successfully stored the word is very happy
>
> Successfully stored the word very happy
>
> Successfully stored the word happy

I tried debugging it, but everything looks good. I track the i / j variables and they're locating the right indexes for the sub-strings. Any idea as to why I would be getting these results?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out using that source!

Answer (score 2):

```
words.push_back(s.substr(i, j-i));
cout<<"Successfully stored the word "<<s.substr(i, j-i)<<endl;
```

Here's your mistake. You find right location but you get substring wrong. Chang j to j-i when get substring.

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to `substr` is the number of characters to take, not the index of the last character. To get the result you want, you should use `s.substr(i, j-i)`